# Best approach to design classes from Database Design?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, logic, relational-database

So, I am modeling a relational database for a simple social network, but I am not sure how I design the relation Friend, I have the following relation for User:

```
User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ASC, username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
password TEXT NOT NULL)
```

At first I designed the friend relation like this:

```
Friend(user_id_parent INTEGER FK, user_id_child INTEGER FK,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id_parent, user_id_child))
```

But the friend relationship in the way I am trying to design means that if A is friend of B, then B is also friend of A. That way, what would be the best approach when I insert new friends?

1. Whenever I insert that A is friend of B, I also insert that B is friend of A?
2. I only insert that A is friend of B, and when I have to search for friends, I look in both columns.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much got it!  I made a fiddle of what you said (changing a bit so that it would work with Sql Server and I could actually run it) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2330/1 .  "Friend" is called a junction table (alternately join table, intersection table).  You enter *one* friend (relationship, junction) record for each friendship.  This is an extremely common structure, although it's often used for non-equal relationships (students:classes) as well as for equal relationships (person:person).  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190651%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.

Your option 1 is sort of true - when you insert a record into the Friend table, it automatically inserts the relationship with both - you very probably don't want to create two records.  Your option 2 is also true - as in the third select in my fiddle - it requires that you look in both columns.

I did put in a bit of complexity you didn't mention - relationship types.  The basic relationship is friends, but there can also be spouses, children, enemies, etc.  And if Carl is Alice's child, the inverse is NOT true.  Even for this, though, you probably wouldn't want to create two join records.  You would probably programmatically adjust for inverses when displaying the relationships.